# Find this Integral using Divergence Theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_S\vec V \cdot \hat n \ dS$$ Where $\vec V=x^2z\hat i+y\hat j-xz^2\hat k$

S is the boundry of the region bounded by $x^2+y^2=z$ and $z=4y$

Though this could have been done easily by stoke's theorem, the question specifically asks for divergence theorem. Integrating is a problem for me here. I get the following in my attempt.

$div \vec v =1$ so,

$$\int_{z=x^2+y^2}^{4y}dz=4y-(x^2+y^2)$$ Then

taking $x=r\cos \theta,y=2+r\sin \theta$

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{2\sin \theta}[4(2+r\sin \theta)-(r^2\cos^2 \theta+2+r\sin \theta)]rdrd\theta$$

Am i working in the right direction ? is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in the right direction, but here is my approach closer to the end of the road.

The curve where they intersect is $x^2 +y^2 =4y$. Switching to polar coordinates we obtain $r^2 = 4r \sin \theta$ or $r = 4 \sin \theta$. The region does not cover a whole circle, hence $\theta \in [ 0, \pi]$ and we have

$$V = \iint\limits_{D} \hspace{-6pt} \int_{x^2+y^2}^{4y} \, dz \, dA = \int_0^{\pi} \hspace{-6pt} \int_0^{4 \sin \theta} (4r \sin \theta - r^2) r \, dr \, d \theta.$$

Proceeding the calculations gives

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi} \hspace{-6pt} \int_0^{4 \sin \theta} 4r^2 \sin (\theta) -r^3 \, dr \, d \theta & = \frac{4}{3} (\sin \theta) r^3 \bigg\vert_0^{4 \sin \theta} - \frac{r^4}{4} \bigg\vert_0^{4 \sin \theta} \, d \theta \\
 & = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{4 \sin \theta}{3} (4 \sin \theta)^3 - \frac{(4 \sin \theta)^4}{4} \, d \theta \\
 & = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{4^4 \sin^4 \theta}{3} - \frac{4^4 \sin^4 \theta}{4} \, d \theta \\
 & = 4^4 \int_0^{\pi} \sin^4 \theta \left( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} \right) \, d \theta \\
 & = \frac{4^4}{12} \int_0^{\pi} \sin^4 \theta \, d \theta \\
 & = \frac{4^4}{12} \cdot \frac{3 \pi}{8} = 8 \pi.
\end{align}
$$